# How do you force an unordered list and a div with a table side by side?

Tags: css, html, position

Not only that but also keep them side by side no matter how the window resizes. Will I have to use a table to accomplish this? Is there a better way?

Note: HTML 4 and HTML 5 answers welcomed.

[An example of what I'm working with.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10319409/428757)

Comment: First off the elements you want side by side should be floated.  The parent element of your floated elements should have a fixed width to act as a container to hold them. This will stop them from floating underneath each other on resize.

Comment: are you looking for a non-floating answer?

Comment: The widths of floating elements should take into account any padding/margin they have on them

Comment: I'm looking for an answer that doesn't require the table tag.

Comment: floating does not require a `<table>` tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you had the following styles set you should be fine:

```
.page
{
    width: 100%;
}

#sidebar
{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    float: left;
    display: block;
    width: 20%;
}

#main
{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    float: left;
    display: block;
    width: 80%;
}
```

if you want some space between these elements account for it in your style:

```
#main
{
    padding: 0 0 2% 0;
    margin: 0;
    float: left;
    display: block;
    width: 78%;
}
```

You'll also want to clear the floats after `#main` with a `<div style="clear: left"></div>` or a clearing element or wrap them in another element which has a [clearfix](http://www.webtoolkit.info/css-clearfix.html) style